# Oracle CONNECT BY recursive and return value a match

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

In the following example:

### TABLE

```
ID  NAME    ATTR
-----------------
1   A1      ROOT
2   A2  
3   A3      VALX
4   A4  
5   A5  
6   A6
```

### RELATIONSHIP

```
ID  CHILD_ID    PARENT_ID
-------------------------
1      6            4
2      5            4
3      4            3
4      3            1
5      2            1
```

### SCHEMA

[image: SCHEMA]

I need a query to get the value of the ATTR column of the PARENT when it is different from null. Raising the levels until you get the first match.
For example with ID 6:

```
ID   NAME    NAME_PARENT     ATTR_PARENT
-----------------------------------------
6     A6          A3            VALX
```

I have tried with:

```
select T.ID, T.NAME, T2.NAME PARENT_NAME, T2.ATTR ATTR_PARENT
from TABLE T
INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIP R
ON R.CHILD_ID = T.ID
INNER JOIN TABLE T2
ON T2.ID = R.PARENT_D
WHERE T2.ATTR IS NOT NULL
START WITH T.ID = 6
CONNECT BY T.ID = PRIOR R.PARENTID 
--and R.PARENTID != prior T.ID
```

And sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does every child have 0 or 1 parents? Or can a child have multiple parents?

Comment: @JoshEller The child can have multiple parents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the [mostly obsolete] `CONNECT BY` clause you can use standard Recursive SQL CTEs (Common Table Expressions).

For example:

```
with
n (id, name, name_parent, attr_parent, parent_id, lvl) as (
  select t.id, t.name, b.name, b.attr, r.parent_id, 1
  from t
  join r on t.id = r.child_id
  join t b on b.id = r.parent_id
  where t.id = 6 -- starting node
 union all 
  select n.id, n.name, b.name, b.attr, r.parent_id, lvl + 1
  from n
  join r on r.child_id = n.parent_id
  join t b on b.id = r.parent_id
  where n.attr_parent is null
)
select id, name, name_parent, attr_parent 
from n
where lvl = (select max(lvl) from n)
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME  NAME_PARENT  ATTR_PARENT
--  ----  -----------  -----------
6   A6    A3           VALX
```

For reference, the data script I used is:

```
create table t (
  id number(6),
  name varchar2(10),
  attr varchar2(10)
);

insert into t (id, name, attr) values (1, 'A1', 'ROOT');
insert into t (id, name, attr) values (2, 'A2', null);
insert into t (id, name, attr) values (3, 'A3', 'VALX');
insert into t (id, name, attr) values (4, 'A4', null);
insert into t (id, name, attr) values (5, 'A5', null);
insert into t (id, name, attr) values (6, 'A6', null);

create table r (
  id number(6),
  child_id number(6),
  parent_id number(6)
);

insert into r (id, child_id, parent_id) values (1, 6, 4);
insert into r (id, child_id, parent_id) values (2, 5, 4);
insert into r (id, child_id, parent_id) values (3, 4, 3);
insert into r (id, child_id, parent_id) values (4, 3, 1);
insert into r (id, child_id, parent_id) values (5, 2, 1);
```

Comment: Why do you think `connect by` is obsolete? It is proprietary to Oracle, while the recursive `with` clause is in the SQL Standard (and it is supported by many other database vendors), but this doesn't make `connect by` obsolete. To the contrary, it is still very actively used, and for a very good reason: when both can do the same work, `connect by` will often be faster (and, often, **much** faster) than recursive `with` clause.

Comment: I made only one modification in the database. Removing the value of the ATTR column in ID 3 and I was still returning the NAME_PARENT = A3, and the ATTR in NULL. Please see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aee12/6

Comment: @DMAVE That was a bug, yes. It's fixed now. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aee12/9

Comment: @mathguy I'm curious about the performance benefit you mention of the `CONNECT BY`. Do you have some documentation of this benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do the whole thing in a single pass of `connect by` - using the various features available for this kind of query (including the `connect_by_isleaf` flag and the `connect_by_root` pseudo-column):

```
select  connect_by_root(r.child_id) as id,
        connect_by_root(t.name)     as name,
        t.name                      as name_parent,
        t.attr                      as attribute_parent
from    r join t on r.child_id = t.id
where   connect_by_isleaf = 1
start   with r.child_id = 6
connect by prior r.parent_id = r.child_id and prior t.attr is null
;

        ID NAME       NAME_PARENT ATTRIBUTE_PARENT
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------------
         6 A6         A3          VALX
```

Note that this will still return a `null` ATTRIBUTE_PARENT, if the entire tree is walked without ever finding an ancestor with non-null ATTRIBUTE. If in fact you only want to show something in the output if an ancestor has a non-null ATTRIBUTE (and allow the output to have no rows if there is no such ancestor), you can change the `where` clause to `where t.attr is not null`. In most cases, though, you would probably want the behavior as I coded it.

I used the tables and data as posted in    @TheImpaler 's answer (thank you for the `create table` and `insert` statements!)

As I commented under his answer: recursive `with` clause is in the SQL Standard, so it has some advantages over `connect by`. However, whenever the same job can be done with `connect by`, it's worth at least testing it that way too. In many cases, due to numerous optimizations Oracle has come up with over time, `connect by` will be much faster.

One reason some developers avoid `connect by` is that they don't spend the time to learn the various features (like the ones I used here). Not a good reason, in my opinion.

Comment: I made only one modification in the database. Removing the value of the ATTR column in ID 3 and I was still returning the NAME_PARENT = A3, and the ATTR in NULL. Please see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aee12/7